# Sitecore WFFM Captcha Detection Thresholds not working

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers

First off, I'm running WFFM 2.3.0 rev.130118.

I have a form with a Captcha field. If I set the Captcha field to display all the time, everything works fine.  If the Captcha field is configured to display if certain Detection Thresholds are met, as far as I can tell, the Captcha is never displayed.

Here is a screenshot of the Detection Threshold dialog:

[image: http://imgur.com/cOMiTSw]

I say "as far as I can tell" because it may be a bit difficult to replicate "suspicious form activity" in your local dev environment. However, as you can see, I've set the visitor submission values to 3 times in 5 minutes.  If I then go and submit the form a number of times beyond that threshold, I'm never presented with a Captcha.

Beyond the Captcha field, it's a basic contact us form with 4 text fields, nothing fancy and WFFM is effectively a "stock" configuration.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I don't see why this is considered off topic. It relates specifically to the  Sitecore Webforms For Marketers module.

Comment: I suppose the best answer can come from Sitecore support since it's a supported module.

Comment: It was probably closed because who ever did so knows nothing about Sitecore and thought it relates to a Google Captcha system

Comment: Reopen voters (maybe @MarkUrsino), could you please state the case for this question being [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?  It seems to be about end user use of a CMS, not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it had to do with the form and its fields having multiple language versions.

Essentially, the site supports multiple languages but I only added a en-US Captcha field and forgot to translate for each supported language.

Even though 3 out of 4 fields involved are shared(Field Link, Required & Parameters) and Title isn't even being utilized in this case, Sitecore assumes the context language and if you don't have a translated version of that field, the intended functionality never gets triggered.